# vba excel - Run-time error '438': object doesn't support this property or method - Opentextfile

Tags: vba, excel

I'm allowing a user to select multiple files and find the file with the most lines in it. When I run the code below, I get a "run-time error '438' on the line with Opentextfile. -> txsInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

```
Dim objFSO, txsInput, strTemp, arrLines
Const ForReading = 1
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'set and determine file picker behaviour
Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

'Launch file picker, exit if no files selected. Hold Ctrl to select multiple files.
If Not fd.Show = -1 Then Exit Sub


'find longest file
For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
    FileName = fd.SelectedItems(i)
    txsInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(FileName, ForReading)

    'Skip lines one by one
    Do While txsInput.AtEndOfStream <> True
        txsInput.SkipLine ' or strTemp = txsInput.ReadLine
    Loop

    If longestFileLength < txsInput.Line - 1 Then
        longestFileLength = txsInput.Line - 1
        longestFileIndex = i
    End If

    'cleanup
    Set objFSO = Nothing
Next i
Cells(headerOffset, 20) = "Length" & longestFileLength
Cells(headerOffset, 21) = "index" & longestFileIndex
```

Comment: `Set objFSO = Nothing` happens *inside* the loop, so on the 2nd iteration its `Nothing` so has no `OpenTextFile()` and you get your error.

Comment: @AlexK. - I guess the OP gets the error on the first iteration...

Comment: Yep your right, the Nothing problem would be error 91

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quick fix (just to avoid the error):

`Dim objFSO, txsInput As Object, strTemp, arrLines`

and

```
Set txsInput = objFSO.OpenTextFile(Filename, ForReading)
```

---

Normal fix - declare the variables correctly, use `Option Explicit` on the top, then declare the following variables:

- fd
- i
- Filename
- longestFileLength
- longestFileIndex
- headerOffset

If you are lucky, your next error would be here:

```
Cells(headerOffset, 20) = "Length" & longestFileLength
```

because `headerOffset` is with value `0`. If you write `headerOffset = 1` on the line before you would avoid it.